# How to get post image root URL?

Tags: plugin-development, permalinks, paths

By using below code, I got Image url like `"http://localhost..."` but I need root path of that image from `"var/www/html/....`
"

```
 $FeaturedImage = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(
 $post->ID ), 'homepage-column1' );
```

Is there any way to get root path of the post thumbnail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`get_attached_file()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_attached_file/) function returns the path to a file based on the attachment ID:

```
$FeaturedImage = get_attached_file( get_post_thumbnail_id() );
```

Getting the path to a specific size is more complicated. WordPress stores the filename for resized versions of the images in as attachment metadata, that can be retrieved with `wp_get_attachment_metadata()`. Once you have the filename of the resized version, you just need to replace the original filename in the path with the resized version's filename:

```
$image_id   = get_post_thumbnail_id();
$image_meta = wp_get_attachment_metadata( $image_id );
$image_path = get_attached_file( $image_id );

if ( isset( $image_meta['sizes']['homepage-column1']['file'] ) ) {
    $image_path = str_replace( $image_meta['file'], $image_meta['sizes']['homepage-column1']['file'], $image_path );
}
```